# Get Resolution and Dimensions of image using ImageMagick

Tags: c#, imagemagick

I have the following code:

```
using (MagickImageCollection tiffPageCollection = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    tiffPageCollection.Read("some.tif");
    foreach (MagickImage tiffPage in tiffPageCollection)
    {
        int dpi = tiffPage.????;
        int height = tiffPage.????;
        int width = tiffPage.????;
    }
}
```

What do I place in ???? to get the respective property.

When I use visual studio to look at available properties and methods I see BaseHeight and BaseWidth, but when google those terms with "MagickImage" (the class) nothing turns up.

Where is the definitive reference documentation for Image Magick?  The only doc I can find on magick.codeplex.com is sample documentation.  That is helpful, but not what I need right now.

I can find other documentation, but it appears to be for the commandline image magic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to ImageMagick APIs (or any library for that matter), your best bet is the source code itself. In your case the [height](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/Source/Magick.NET/Shared/MagickImage.cs#L689), [width](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/Source/Magick.NET/Shared/MagickImage.cs#L879) and [resolution](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/Source/Magick.NET/Shared/MagickImage.cs#L540) are defined in `MagickImage.cs`.

Your code would be:

```
using (MagickImageCollection tiffPageCollection = new MagickImageCollection())
{
    tiffPageCollection.Read("some.tif");
    foreach (MagickImage tiffPage in tiffPageCollection)
    {
        Density d = tiffPage.Density;
        int height = tiffPage.Height;
        int width = tiffPage.Width;
    }
}
```

Comment: I accepted this answer, but if in the future someone adds an answer with actual documentation of the method/properties, then I will accept that answer.  +1 for this answer because it gave links to the source in question.

Comment: @BeKindToNewUsers I upvote your comment but it's really a proxy upvote of your username.